# Calculating Values in Radio Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a nutrition calculator. It should the values in the radio button and display the value, but I have no idea why it isn't working. The code below doesn't seem to work.

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.options').on('change', 'input', function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    var inputType = $self.attr('type');

    if (inputType == 'radio') {
        $self.parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (inputType == 'checkbox') {
        $self.parent('li').toggleClass('active');
    }
    runUpdate();
});

});

function runUpdate() {

//get the sum of the elements

var calories = $(".caloriesSum", '.active').sum();
var fat = $(".fatSum", '.active').sum();
var satfat = $(".satfatSum", '.active').sum();
var carbs = $(".carbsSum", '.active').sum();
var protein = $(".proteinSum", '.active').sum();
var sodium = $(".sodiumSum", '.active').sum();
var chloresterol = $(".chloesterolSum", '.active').sum();

//update the total

$("#totalCalories").text(+calories.toString());
$("#totalFat").text(+fat.toString());
$("#totalSatFat").text(+satfat.toString());
$("#totalCarbs").text(+carbs.toString());
$("#totalProtein").text(+protein.toString());
$("#totalSodium").text(+sodium.toString());
$("#totalChloresterol").text(+chloresterol.toString());
}?
 </script>


<style type="text/css">
ul.options li span {display:none;}
#totals {padding:20px; background:#eee;}
#totals span {font-weight:bold;}
h4,ul {margin:0 0 15px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" id="nutform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <h2>Taqueria Nutritionals</h2>

        <h4>Pick Your Meal</h4>

  <!--Radio Buttons with Values -->

        <ul class="options">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="wwheatt" name="meal"     value="whole_wheat_tortilla"> Whole Wheat Tortilla

   <!-- This class contains the values that it should add -->

                <span class="caloriesSum">280</span>
                <span class="fatSum">6</span>
                <span class="satfatSum">0</span>
                <span class="carbsSum">44</span>
                <span class="proteinSum">8</span>
                <span class="sodiumSum">340</span>
                <span class="chloesterolSum">0</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="meal" value="flour_tortilla" > Flour Tortilla
                <span class="caloriesSum">290</span>
                <span class="fatSum">6</span>
                <span class="satfatSum">2</span>
                <span class="carbsSum">49</span>
                <span class="proteinSum">9</span>
                <span class="sodiumSum">770</span>
                <span class="chloesterolSum">0</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="meal" value="naked" > Naked, zero nutrients
                <span class="caloriesSum">0</span>
                <span class="fatSum">0</span>
                <span class="satfatSum">0</span>
                <span class="carbsSum">0</span>
                <span class="proteinSum">0</span>
                <span class="sodiumSum">0</span>
                <span class="chloesterolSum">0</span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <h4>Select Your Protein</h4>

        <ul class="options">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="protein" value="steak" > Steak
                <span class="caloriesSum">230</span>
                <span class="fatSum">9</span>
                <span class="satfatSum">3</span>
                <span class="carbsSum">3</span>
                <span class="proteinSum">32</span>
                <span class="sodiumSum">170</span>
                <span class="chloesterolSum">90</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="protein" value="carnitas" > Carnitas
                <span class="caloriesSum">210</span>
                <span class="fatSum">9</span>
                <span class="satfatSum">3</span>
                <span class="carbsSum">2</span>
                <span class="proteinSum">29</span>
                <span class="sodiumSum">490</span>
                <span class="chloesterolSum">90</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="protein" value="chicken" > Chicken
                <span class="caloriesSum">190</span>
                <span class="fatSum">2</span>
                <span class="satfatSum">0</span>
                <span class="carbsSum">4</span>
                <span class="proteinSum">35</span>
                <span class="sodiumSum">560</span>
                <span class="chloesterolSum">90</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="protein" value="tofu"> Tofu
            </li>
        </ul>

        <h4>The Add-ins</h4>

        <ul class="options">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="the_addins" value="white_rice"> White Rice
            <span class="fatSum">9</span>
                <span class="satfatSum">3</span>
                <span class="carbsSum">2</span>
                <span class="proteinSum">29</span>
                <span class="sodiumSum">490</span>
                <span class="chloesterolSum">90</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="the_addins" value="brown_rice"> Brown Rice
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="the_addins" value="black_beans"> Black                                    Beans
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="the_addins" value="pinto_beans"> Pinto Beans
            </li>
        </ul>

        <h4>Salsas</h4>

        <ul class="options">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="salsas" value="pico_de_gallo"> Pico De Gallo
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="salsas" value="tomatillo_salsa"> Tomatillo Salsa
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="salsas" value="roasted_corn_salsa"> Roasted Corn Salsa
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="salsas" value="fire_roasted_red_salsa"> Fire Roasted Red Salsa
            </li>
        </ul>    

        <h4>Add-ins</h4>

        <ul class="options">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="addins" value="lettuce"> Lettuce
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="addins" value="shredded_cheese"> Shredded Cheese
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="addins" value="crema"> Crema
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="addins" value="chipotle_crema"> Chipotle Crema
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="addins" value="guacamole"> Guacamole
            </li>
        </ul>            


  <!-- This is where the values should display -->

        <div id="totals">

            <h4>Totals</h4>

            <ul>


                <li>Calories: <span id="totalCalories"> </span></li>
                <li>Fat: <span id="totalFat"> </span>g</li>
                <li>Sat. Fat: <span id="totalSatFat"> </span>g</li>
                <li>Carbs: <span id="totalCarbs"> </span>g</li>
                <li>Protein: <span id="totalProtein"> </span>g</li>
                <li>Sodium: <span id="totalSodium"> </span>mg</li>
                <li>Cholesterol: <span id="totalChloresterol"> </span>mg</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  <!-- #totals -->

  </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: just show the relevant code or post a test fiddle

Comment: Your code depends on jQuery but you haven't loaded it.

Comment: Hi IsisCode, i tried adding in this line to run the function but the attempt failed too.. I am quite bad in my programming. Sorry for the inconvenience. Would really value any of your input.<input type="radio" id="wwheatt" name="meal" value="whole_wheat_tortilla" onclick="runUpdate(this.value);"> Whole Wheat Tortilla

Comment: @Vithiyah Have you taken steps to load jquery?

Comment: @kennypu sorry for the trouble here is the jfiddle jsfiddle.net/Vithiya/VvcTM

Comment: @ChrisFarmer i tried loading the jquery but didnt work. not sure whether i tried the correct method..

Comment: Do you even know what is failing?  I think you would benefit from redefining success and starting smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a $.sum plugin that adds the values of a jQuery collection. I dropped one in place ([first hit on a Google search](http://jqueryminute.com/calculating-the-sum-of-inputs/)) and your code works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/QM9gP/

```
$.fn.sum = function() {
    var sum = 0; 
    this.each(function() {
        if ( $(this).is(':input') ) {
            var val = $(this).val();
        } else {
            var val = $(this).text();
        }
        sum += parseFloat( ('0' + val).replace(/[^0-9-\.]/g, ''), 10 );
    });
    return sum;
};

$('.options').on('change', 'input', function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    var inputType = $self.attr('type');

    if (inputType == 'radio') {
        $self.parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (inputType == 'checkbox') {
        $self.parent('li').toggleClass('active');
    }
    runUpdate();
});

function runUpdate() {
  console.log('run update');

    // get the sum of the elements

    var calories = $(".caloriesSum", '.active').sum();
    var fat = $(".fatSum", '.active').sum();
    var satfat = $(".satfatSum", '.active').sum();
    var carbs = $(".carbsSum", '.active').sum();
    var protein = $(".proteinSum", '.active').sum();
    var sodium = $(".sodiumSum", '.active').sum();
    var chloresterol = $(".chloesterolSum", '.active').sum();

    // update the total

    $("#totalCalories").text(+calories.toString());
    $("#totalFat").text(+fat.toString());
    $("#totalSatFat").text(+satfat.toString());
    $("#totalCarbs").text(+carbs.toString());
    $("#totalProtein").text(+protein.toString());
    $("#totalSodium").text(+sodium.toString());
    $("#totalChloresterol").text(+chloresterol.toString());
}
```

Comment: Hi Nate, i tried replacing my codes with yours but still it doesnt work. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Please look carefully -- if you look at my live JSFiddle, you'll see a functioning example. If you're still having trouble, you've got something wrong in your implementation separate from what you've provided here.

Comment: Nate, I certainly have no idea why my page doesnt work and the fiddle works. I have added my html page here http://temp-share.com/show/Pf3Yy4Oq2. If you don mind please help me take a look at it. THANK YOU SOOO MUCH.. Would be really grateful..

Comment: @Vithiyah Please make it easier on everyone and use something like jsfiddle where you have a live version that's easy to work with.  Perhaps if you tried doing it this way you would also recognize your problem easier.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer sorry for the trouble here is the jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Vithiya/VvcTM/

Comment: Make sure you've got the jQuery framework selected. http://jsfiddle.net/VvcTM/1/ Once you do that, your fiddle works.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer thank you so much for your help. The code is working  already. It was such a trivial problem which i overlooked. Thank you so much once again :)

Comment: @Nate thank you so much for your help. The code is working already. It was such a trivial problem which i overlooked. Thank you so much once again :) You were such a great help. Really appreciate much :)